# Removing desktop.ini when startup

Tags: windows, boot, window

I have laptop with Windows 8.1 operating system at home. Everytime I open my laptop a desktop.ini file always open up 
it contains the following text:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21787
```

Even though I open the starup folder and seach for .ini or desktop nothing shows. Even I show hidden files, run cleaner using CCleaner and scan using 360 Total Security. Nothing happen. I hope that I've got possible solution with it. And know the possible cause of this problem.

Comment: Use Sysinternals AutoRuns program to check what is launched at startup.

Comment: You have used AutoRuns to determine any malicious software that is starting cause this behavior isn't being done by legitimate software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you act as if you're about to save the document then you'll see the correct path of the file then just browse to that same directory through an explorer window to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following path as the file may reside in there.

[image: Possible File Path]

In addition, run cmd.exe > msconfig and see what is loading at startup.